# tf.slice with one constant size component

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Let `image_shape` and `crop_shape` be tensors of shape `[None, None, None, 64]`

I can do the following (propose that `image_shape` is greater than `crop_shape`)

```
image_shape = tf.shape(inputs)[1:-1]
crop_shape = tf.shape(shape_image)[1:-1]
n_channels = inputs.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
size = tf.concat([(-1,), image_size, (64,)], axis=0)
x = tf.slice(inputs, begin=begin, size=size)
```

The resulting tensor `x` will be of shape `[None, None, None, None]` but I'd like to get  `[None, None, None, 64]`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`x.set_shape([None, None, None, 64])` solves my problem